# How to manage version from git-describe when implementing a new feature?

Tags: git, version, semantic-versioning

I am working on this development:

```
* a3bde21 (feature)
* bdf3b22
* 5a4d8e9 (master, tag: v0.1.0)
* 47312aa
* abd2111
```

So `git describe` will give me `v0.1.0`. The problem is that I am implementing a feature which is not anymore the `v0.1.0`. If I build my program and give the executable to someone, it will think it is the `v0.1.0`, but it is not.

So I can follow to [semver](http://semver.org/) and add a build number:

```
0.1.0+a3bde21
```

But is it still seen as the version `0.1.0`.

How should I address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion). It is far more powerful and configurable than `git describe`. It generates [semver](http://semver.org) compliant version numbers.

Comment: Could be interesting, but even on the `README.md` or on the readthedocs documentation, there is no `tl;dr;` explaination of "What does GitVersion do". I am quite shy with such huge project running on mono...

Comment: @nowox I agree that it is a bit daunting. But your question has more depth than you perhaps think. It leads to the underlying question: what is your branching strategy? Depending on the answer, it leads to different version numbering. In your example, the feature branch is presumably a beta version, which should be reflected in the version.